# module.exports is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, undefined, read-write

I am currently new to `Node JS`, and today I was trying to **read** data from a file `data.json`.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{"username":"rahul_v7","password":"9673"} {"username":"7vik","password":"3248"} {"username":"pradypot_2","password":"6824"} {"username":"ad_1","password":"9284"} {"username":"premchand_4","password":"4346"}
```

And, I was using the below code present in a file `GetData.js`,  to read the data present in the `data.json`:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

let res = '', resObjs = [];
let fin = fs.createReadStream('F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/data.json', 'utf-8');
fin.on('data', data => {
    if(data.length > 0) res += data;
}).on('end', () => {
    if(res.length > 0) {
        let resArr = res.trim().split(' ');

        for(let i = 0; i < resArr.length; i++) {
            resObjs.push(JSON.parse(resArr[i]));
        }

        module.exports.objects = resObjs;
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am **exporting** the `resObjs` array, which is actually an **array of objects**, to an another file named `AppendData.js`, which is given below:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const getObjs = require('./GetData');

console.log(getObjs.objects);
```

But, when I run `AppendData.js` in `Node.js 9.3.0 (ia32)`, it gives the following **output**:

[image: Output Image]

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I knew very well before posting that it could be a possible duplicate, and that is the reason why I searched tons of times on Stack Overflow for the related topic. But, I wasn't able to solve the problem. Anyways, thanks for the link :)

Comment: Doesn't windows use backslashes for navigation.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir, Can you explain it more?

Comment: @Rahul I'll post a propper answer.

Comment: Make sure your JSON data's format is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because you're trying to use the objects in `AppendData.js` before they are loaded on `GetData.js` due to `fs.createReadStream` being asynchronous. To fix this just make `module.exports` be a function that expect a callback in `GetData.js` like:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(callback) {
    let res = '', resObjs = [];
    let fin = fs.createReadStream('F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/data.json', 'utf-8');
    fin.on('data', data => {
        if(data.length > 0) res += data;
    }).on('end', () => {
        if(res.length > 0) {
            let resArr = res.trim().split(' ');

            for(let i = 0; i < resArr.length; i++) {
                resObjs.push(JSON.parse(resArr[i]));
            }

            callback(resObjs);                        // call the callback with the array of results
        }
    });
}
```

Which you can then use like this in `AppendData.js`:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const getObjs = require('./GetData');                 // getObjs is now a function

getObjs(function(objects) {
    console.log(objects);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the objects before they've been read. Remember that your code reading the stream runs *asynchronously*, and nothing in your code attempts to coordinate it with module loading. So `AppendData.js` isn't seeing the `objects` export because it doesn't exist yet as of when that code runs.

Instead, return a *promise* of the objects that `AppendData.js` can consume; see `***` comments:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

// *** Export the promise
module.exports.objectsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let res = '', resObjs = [];
    let fin = fs.createReadStream('F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/data.json', 'utf-8');
    fin.on('data', data => {
        if(data.length > 0) res += data;
    }).on('end', () => {
        if(res.length > 0) {
            let resArr = res.trim().split(' ');

            for(let i = 0; i < resArr.length; i++) {
                resObjs.push(JSON.parse(resArr[i]));
            }

            resolve(resObjs); // *** Resolve the promise
        }
    }).on('error', error => {
         reject(error);       // *** Reject the promise
    });
});
```

Note I added a handler for errors.

And then:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const getObjs = require('./GetData');

getObjs.objectsPromise
    .then(console.log) 
    .catch(error => {
        // Do something
    });
```

Again note the error handler.

Comment: *(Doh! If you see `.error(error => {` near the end of the answer, hit refresh. Silly typo.)*

Comment: Nice, it worked for me! But, can you provide me a callback version of the same? It would be awesome!

Comment: @Rahul - Simple callbacks are a poorer choice than promises, not least because a promise can be used by multiple consumers. Doing this with a simple callback would actually be more complicated.