# Nodejs module.exports return value is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting directory information through `ssh` and am exporting some details to be stored in db.

```
// details.js
const SSH = require('simple-ssh');
const config = require('./config');
let count = 0;  
let update; 
const ssh = new SSH({
        host: config.host,
        user: config.user,
        pass: config.pass});
ssh.start(); 
getInfo(config.dirpath);

function getInfo(dir){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    ssh
        .exec(`date '+%F %r' -r  ${dir}`,{
            out: function (stdout) 
            {  update = stdout
            },
            err: function (stderr) { console.log(stderr); 
            } 
            })
        .exec(`ls ${dir}/ ` ,{
              out: function (stdout) 
             {stdout = stdout.split("\n"); 
               for (var i =0; i < stdout.length; i++){
                childinfo(dir+"/"+stdout[i]);
            }},
            err: function (stderr) { console.log(stderr); } 
        })  
     resolve(update)
  )}     
}

function childinfo(dirName){
 return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    ssh
      .exec(`ls  ${dirName} | wc -l `,{
        out: function (stdout) 
        {  count = count + parseInt(stdout);
           resolve(count);
      },
        err: function (stderr) { console.log(stderr);}
    })
})
}
module.exports ={
   getInfo,
   childInfo
}
```

The values are exported before it can be updated. I tried using async-await and Promises. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437362/module-exports-is-returning-undefined).

I am getting reject message even though all `console.logs` are being executed properly.

I am new to `javascript` and hence not able to use async-await properly.

```
//export.js
const fileInfo = require('./details.js');
const config = require('./config');

async function getAllDetails(){
   let d = await fileInfo.getInfo(config.path);
   let c = await fileInfo.childInfo();
   return [d,c];
}

(async function(){
       let info = await getAllDetails();
       console.log(info[1]);
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @SebastianSimon are you sure about that duplicate ? The variables are defined in the correct scope. It seems to be an issue about module exporting. `count` should at least be "0", not undefined.

Comment: Did you check what was the value of `fileInfo` ?

Comment: Rather than returning those values i.e. count and update return the functions that return those values, and wait for them to finish executing. Use async await, or callbacks. You are exporting the values, and those values are being modified later after function finishes executing.

Comment: @Seblor count is not undefined, its 0. Like I said the  using SetTimeout I am able to import values  fileInfo.count and fileInfo.update.

Comment: I never said that `count` is `undefined`. The duplicate target is about variables being _unaltered_ when modified asynchronously in a function, which almost certainly happens here as well.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I have commented out the exporting function method, even that doesn't work. My only workaround is using setTimeout for both module.exports and in import file for values to be loaded and its not efficient.

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates. `update` etc. are modified *asynchronously*, that is why `setTimeout` "works": enough time has passed that the async call has completed.

Comment: "*I tried using async-await and Promises.*" - please show us *what* you tried. Otherwise we can only refer you to the canonical questions.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hey thanks for the link, its still returning undefined. I don't know where I am going wrong. Don't know how to resolve the second function as its being called from the first function. I have edited the code.

Comment: @Bergi hey, I tried similar variations of what I have edited, just not with IIFE.

Comment: You cannot just replace the `return update` with `resolve(update)` - the variable still isn't assigned when that line runs. Instead, you need to place `resolve(stdout)` instead of the `update = stdout`.

Comment: The `childinfo` needs to be promisified as well

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot. I am able to get values from `getInfo()`. The parameters for `childinfo` is passes from `getInfo()` and I am unable to import that.